# setState on empty field in JSON object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

I have the empty field `ModifiedBy`.  I need to populate it with a username stored in session storage, `userInfo.name`.

```
const [details, setDetails] = useState("");

const handleCreateData = (e) => {
    setDetails((prev) => {
        return { ...prev, ModifiedBy: userInfo.name };
    });
}
```

This method only works when `ModifiedBy` is already populated in data.  I need to be able to populate `ModifiedBy` when it is empty, and update it is populated.

A quick example of my JSON

```
{
  "ModifiedBy": "Ciaran Crowley"
}
```

Comment: Hi! I'd expect that to work, although not necessarily for the reasons you expect (when you use property spread on a string, you get no properties); your initial state really should be `{}`. But still, again, I'd expect that to work. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: How exactly is this failing?  This should indeed set the `ModifiedBy` property in state to whatever value is in `userInfo.name`.  Can you provide a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: There are no errors.  The value `userInfo.name` is simply not appended to `ModifiedBy`.  I can console log `userInfo.name` and get the correct user name.

Comment: @CiaranCrowley: How are you observing this problem?  Because [your code demonstrably works](https://codesandbox.io/s/great-currying-5rddyp).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const handleCreateData = (e) => {
 setDetails((prev) => {
    prev.ModifiedBy = userInfo.name || ''
    return prev;
 });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.